# Ionic: promise goes to error even though it's resolved

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, ionic-framework, promise

I'm building my first ionic app and I have a problem with one of my promises.

The app talks with a REST api to login and register, the login part works but for the register part every time I fill in the form and submit I get the error message, even if the user is created (I can see him in the database of the api) and I can't figure out why, even though the promise is resolved, I still get the error message.

the controller.js code:

```
wannaPlay.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, AuthService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
    $scope.player = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        password: '',
        email: ''
    };

    $scope.signup = function() {
        AuthService.register($scope.player).then(function(msg) {
            $state.go('outside.login');
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Enregistrement effectué !',
                template: msg
            });
        }, function(errMsg) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Erreur lors de l\'enregistrement !',
                template: errMsg
            });
        });
    };
})
```

the services.js code:

```
var register = function(player) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
        $http.post(API_ENDPOINT.url + '/playersignup', player).then(function(result) {
            if (result.data.succes) {
                resolve(result.data.msg);
            } else {
                reject(result.data.msg);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you checked the http request and response? Could it be result.data.succes is false, or not defined?

Comment: Your services.js code is stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican thanks, it was false, "succes" was not defined, it was "success"

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks, I'll give it a read, always up for learning better coding practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the REST api really returning a boolean called 'succes', not 'success'?

Maybe it's just that typo. Else you should consider putting logmessages or breakpoints to see what you recieve from the REST backend like this:

```
console.log(result);
if (result.data.succes) {
    console.log("success");                
    resolve(result.data.msg);
} else {
    console.log("error");                
    reject(result.data.msg);
}
```